# SSAS Configuration Question

Tags: sql-server, ssas

With SSIS and SSRS (and Power BI Report Server), you can install the service on one machine and the catalog database (SSISDB or ReportServer) on a different machine or clustered AOAG instance. Is the same sort of thing possible with SSAS where you would install the service on one machine and have your cubes or tabular models on another?

Comment: I don't think you're comparing the same sort of things - the SSAS service running on one server with "cubes or tabular models on another", would be the same as saying can you run the SQL Database Engine on one server and have the database files (.mdf, .ldf) on a different server.  SSIS and SSRS make a connection to other services that provide the access to data, they don't connect directly to the database files.

Comment: There are approaches that you could take to allow SQL Database Engine or Analysis Services to locate their database files on a network path (so, technically, the database on a "different server"), but it's really not ideal, and I can't even necessarily easily think of a situation where you would need to do this .....

Comment: Bear in mind that you do also have to consider the licensing implications of separating out different SQL Server components onto different servers.  SQL licensing gets pretty complicated these days, though, with virtual servers, processors, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that you would gain anything from doing this. I'm more insterested in whether it's even possible.  While you can have several SSIS or SSRS instances in a scale-out deployment with a single database engine for the catalog, I'm not sure that SSAS works that way.  It seems like SSAS is more like a specialized database engine than merely a service, but it;s the one part of the BI stack that I've never really worked with, so I could easily be missing something 'obvious' to people who have had to support it.

Comment: Well, much like the Database Engine has some settings within it that tell it what the physical paths are to various database files, so Analysis Services will have its own settings that tell it where its database files are - really no different, particularly.  So, as I said SSAS is, architecturally, far more analogous to the Database Engine, as opposed to SSIS and SSRS.  That is - SSAS is a data source itself (like Database Engine), whereas SSIS and SSRS are performing their own particular functions that just happen to require a connection to a data source (which may be local, or remote)

Answer (score 1):

For those that can't be bothered reading through comments...

Thanks to [Craig](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/271637/craig), I understand that while SSIS and SSRS/PBIRS are services in search of data sources (Excel, SQL Server, CSV, Oracle, SSAS, etc.), SSAS *is* a data source, similar to the SQL Database Engine. As such, there are configuration patterns that SSIS and SSRS/PBIRS can use which are just not available to SSAS.